# Android Autocomplete textview onitemclicklistener not working

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview, onitemclicklistener

I am using autocomplete textview in my application for which i am using simple cursor adapter.
I have used both setFilterQueryProvider and setCursorToStringConverter in application.
It is showing list of options after entering word in autocomplete textview but when i am trying to select any of the option from that list its not getting selected. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setOnItemSelectedListener

searchAutoCompleteTextView
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(SelectItemActivity.this,
                            "No data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: I am using this code in onitemselected listener:               Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
   String DisplayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
   
 textView.setText(DisplayName);